# IE dont send if-none-match or etag header

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-cache

i have an Microsoft WebApi that on a specific route returns a header that allowed caching...

but on a new request the ie dont send the etag or if-none-match header..

on chrome this works fine ..

Response on IE

[image]

Request on IE
[image]